# Express - nodejs app spinning indefinitely when a module is browsed

Tags: node.js, express

*Note - I am newbie trying to write my first application using express.
I followed a video tutorial and did not follow any e-book or document tutorial to learn. Hence finding it difficult to find out the thing I am missing by reading an ebook now.*

I have the following files -

```
app.js
/src/routes/testRoutes.js
/src/controllers/testController.js
```

Following is my app.js file -

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var port = 5000;

var testRouter = require('./src/routes/testRoutes');
app.use('/Test',testRouter);

app.get('/',function(req,res){
        res.send("Hello world");
});

app.listen(port,function(err){
    console.log("Running port on "+port);
});
```

testRoutes.js

```
var express = require('express');
var testRouter = express.Router();

var router = function()
{
    var testController = require('../controllers/testController')(null);
    testRouter.route('/hello').get(testController.hello);

    return testRouter;
};


module.exports = router;
```

testController.js

```
//Will use revealing module pattern
var testController = function(botService)   
{
    var hello = function(req,res){
        console.log("Inside bot controller");
    };

    return {
        hello:hello
    }
}

module.exports = testController;
```

If I browse `http://localhost:5000/` after running `node app`I can see a `Hello world` but if I browse `localhost:5000/Test`, it spins indefinitely. 
For now, I would just like to display some message on the browser directly from the controller file.

**Update**

With the following modification to the router file, testRoutes.js (removing the function), and adding a `res.send()` to the controller, I am able to make it work (stop the spinning and display the message) -

```
var express = require('express');
var testRouter = express.Router();
var testController = require('../controllers/testController');

testRouter.get('/world',testController.hello); 
module.exports = testRouter;
```

But, I am still not able to make it work using the function in the route file, which can take parameters. I went through the links https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Server-side/Express_Nodejs/routes and http://expressjs.com/en/guide/routing.html.

**Update 2**

With reference to @SatishPatel's answer, changing the contents of my controller file to the following format worked for me -

```
function something()
{
    return 5;
}
//Following works but above does not 
module.exports = {
hello : function(req, res){
   res.send('Get a book '+something())
},
getAllBooks : function(req, res){
   res.send('Get all book');
}
}
```

However, I would like to make it work while I use the revealing module pattern, as mentioned in my question description above. If I use the following in my controller -

```
//Will use revealing module pattern

var testController = function()   
{
    function something()
    {
        return 5;
    }

    var hello = function(req,res){
        //console.log("Inside bot controller");
        res.send("Hello world");
    };

    return {
        hello:hello
    }
}

module.exports = testController;
```

Following is the error I am getting on `npm start` -

```
D:\lab\nodejs_scraper\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:202
        throw new Error(msg);
        ^

Error: Route.get() requires callback functions but got a [object Undefined]
    at Route.(anonymous function) [as get] (D:\lab\nodejs_scraper\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:202:15)
    at Object.<anonymous> (D:\lab\nodejs_scraper\src\routes\testRoutes.js:7:28)
    at Module._compile (module.js:570:32)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:579:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:487:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:446:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:438:3)
    at Module.require (module.js:497:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:20:19)
    at Object.<anonymous> (D:\lab\nodejs_scraper\app.js:6:18)
```

An acceptable solution to the question would be one which solves this.

**Update 3**

Marking as resolved because the spinning problem got solved after adding a `res.send()` in the controller.

Comment: Thank you for that. I looked at it but it does not talk about how to use a separate router file.

Comment: did you try separating you routes and controllers the way it has explained. I hope this would help https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Server-side/Express_Nodejs/routes

Comment: @SatishPatel yes I did now. Thank you. I am now able to make it work as given there. But still not able to make it work using a function in the route file. Please check question update.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably you can separate your controller and routes as follows:

**server.js**

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var routes = require('./routes/index');
var port =5000;
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true}));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use('/',routes);
app.listen(port,function(err){
    console.log("Running port on "+port);
});
```

**route.js**

```
var express = require('express');
var bookCtrl = require('../controllers/bookCtrl');
var router = express.Router();
router.route('/').get(function(req,res){
    res.send('you are on root url');
});
router.route('/book').get(bookCtrl.getBook);
router.route('/allbooks').get(bookCtrl.getAllBooks);
/* Write all you apis here and control them in controller*/
module.exports = router;
```

**bookCtrl.js**

```
module.exports = {
getBook : function(req, res){
   res.send('Get a book')
},
getAllBooks : function(req, res){
   res.send('Get all book');
}
}
```

Folder structure as in image
[image: folder structure]

Comment: A +1 for your answer because changing the contents of my controller file to the format you have given worked for me. Thank you for that. However, I would like to make it work with the revealing module pattern, as mentioned in my question. There is something wrong in what I have done. Would like to get it solved.

Comment: Please check my update 2 in the question, and see if you can help further.

Comment: I don't know why but I tend to be confused about what you want to achieve but the solution I have provided also follows module revealing pattern and I think you need to look carefully again. Please correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: Revealing pattern, as per my understanding is one where there is a return statement inside the controller's function declaration, which returns a json object of only name/value pairs of only the functions, in the end (after function declarations) to be made visible - `return {hello:hello,world:world}` e.g. I have given a sample in my original  question body.

Comment: Ok, I am accepting the answer because the spinning problem was because I did not put a res.send() in my controller.